# Regular Expression in Find command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to list out the files which starts with a number and ends with ".c" extension. The following is the find command which is used. But, it does not give
the expected output.

Command:

```
find -type f -regex "^[0-9].*\\.c$"
```

Comment: `.` matches any character. Try `[.]` or `\.` Also, `-regex` matches the full path, not the filename.

Comment: I already try this. But it does not work

Comment: @Mohan As knittl said find doesn't print just the filename, so something like this would work: `find -type f -regex '^[.][/][0-9].*.c'`

Comment: This also does not give expected output. Because  "./<directory name>/..../<filename>". You syntax will work only when the command executed within the same directory. for recursive search the following is the command which gives expected output. find -type f -regex ".*/[0-9].*\.c$".

Comment: You could dispense with the regex here, as it seems to be complicating things, and just use a glob pattern, as in `find -type f -name '[0-9]*.c'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the regex option works with the full path and you specified only the file name. From `man find`:

> ```
>    -regex pattern
>          File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole
>          path, not a search.  For example, to match a file named './fubar3', you can use
>          the  regular  expression  '.*bar.'  or  '.*b.*3',  but  not 'f.*r3'. 
>          The regular expressions understood by find are by default Emacs Regular
>          Expressions, but this can be changed with the -regextype option.
> ```

Try with this:

```
find -type f -regex ".*/[0-9][^/]+\.c$"
```

where you explicitly look for a string where *"the format of your filename follows any string that terminates with a slash"*

**UPDATE:** I made a correction to the regex. I changed `.*` in the filename to `[^\]+` as after *"any string that terminates with a slash"* we don't want to find a slash in that part of the string because it wouldn't be a filename but another directory!

**NOTE:** The matching `.*` can be very harmful...

Answer (score 2):

Just use `-name` option. It accepts pattern for the last component of the path name as the doc says:

> ```
> -name pattern
>
>          True if the last component of the pathname being examined matches
>          pattern.  Special shell pattern matching characters (``['',
>          ``]'', ``*'', and ``?'') may be used as part of pattern.  These
>          characters may be matched explicitly by escaping them with a
>          backslash (``\'').
> ```

So:

```
$ find -type f -name "[0-9]*.c"
```

should work.